# Default browser style differences between sites?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, user-agent

I recently had a site within Chrome start returning a different set of user agent styles than what I see being returned for another domain.  What could cause this?

**My Domain** - Includes font-size: medium which renders as 16px...
[image]

**getbootstrap.com** - Does not include a second user agent stylesheet and renders at 14px...
[image]

Comment: Compare the doctypes

Comment: @jedifans  Thanks.  It's been so long since I ran into a doctype issue that I forgot the behavior it causes.  Turns out I had an HTML comment being echo'd out in PHP before the doctype and it broke the page.

Comment: Woop, glad you solved it!